# What is the semantic difference between a relational noun that is used predicatively and one that is not used predicatively?

Tags: syntax

A relational noun such as *father* can take two arguments, e.g.

(1) a.  Bill is Jane’s father.

(2) a.  Jane’s father is friendly.

It is, I believe, natural to view the relational noun *father* in (1) as a predicate taking the two arguments *Bill* and *Jane*. Given this analysis of *father* in sentence (1), I am wondering how *father* in sentence (2) is analyzed, since it is functioning there as the subject argument of the predicate is *friendly*. One might render the predicate-argument analyses of these two sentences as follows:

(1)  b.  father (Bill, Jane)

(2)  b.  friendly (Jane’s father)

It seems that there is a qualitative difference across sentences (1a) and (2a) regarding the semantic status of *father*. In particular, what are the arguments of the relational noun *father* in sentence (2a)? Can we still view *father* in (2a) as taking two arguments? If yes, what is the other argument of *father* there – the one argument of *father* in (2) is obviously *Jane*?

Any tips about where this issue is addressed in the literature on predicates would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't this also the case for a non-relational noun: "Bill is Jane's doctor", "Jane's doctor is friendly"? Or even: "Bill is the professor", "the professor is friendly"?

Comment: I don't think relationality has anything to do with it. The basic difference between  predicate nouns and others is that one is outfitted like a verb, with auxiliaries and inflections, and the other isn't. Though at some semantic level, every meaningful lexical item is its own predicate (e.g, "There exists an X such that FATHER (X, Jane")) and that will be specified in a sufficiently deep analysis.

Comment: In the constructed language Lojban, any predicate (including its arguments) can be turned into an argument by preceding it with an "article". So from the predicate _patfu la Djein_ "is a father to Jane" we can get _le patfu be la Djein_ "the individual(s) I am describing as satisfying the predicate 'is the father to Jane'" ('be' is syntactic glue, to keep the argument within the description).

Comment: Thanks for the comments! The difference between predicate nouns and others that are not is particularly pertinant here.